# Why the Main Page Showed Up Before Login Page?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As my expectation, user should not see any page until they signed in.

**current behavior when executing app:**
show main page(about one second) -> show login page

**expected behavior:**
show login page -> signed in -> show main page

Questions:

1. How to modify the current behavior to expected behavior ?
2. According to running flow(attached below), the login page is triggered before "MainActivity's fragment: onCreate". Why the main page showed up before login page ?
3. After the main thread calling the startActivityForResult(), should it stop and waiting for user's login ? why it keep running ?

Thank you very much for your help.

---

There are one activity and two fragments in the APP.
FirebaseAuth UI(login page) is triggered on onResume() method.

```
Here is the app's running flow:
MainActivity: onCreate: 
MainActivity: onStart: 
MainActivity: onResume: 
MainActivity: startLoginProcess: Show Login page
MainActivity's fragment: onCreate: 
MainActivity's fragment: onActivityCreated: 
MainActivity's fragment: onStart: 
MainActivity's fragment: onResume: 
MainActivity's fragment: onPause: 
MainActivity: onPause: 
MainActivity's fragment: onStop: 
MainActivity: onStop:
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android.fastorder">

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStatListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeScreen();
    setupLogin();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: ");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStatListener);
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStatListener);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ");
}

private void initializeScreen() {
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PanelFragmentAdapter panelFragmentAdapter = new PanelFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            MainActivity.this);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(panelFragmentAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "signed in success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "user canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "signed in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void setupLogin() {
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthStatListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // user is signed in
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // user is signed out
                startLoginProcess();

            }
        }
    };
}

private void startLoginProcess() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startLoginProcess: Show Login page");
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}

/**
 * Created by yorick on 2018/2/2.
 */

public class PanelFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private String[] mTitles = new String[]{"menu", "order"};

    public PanelFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = PanelOrderFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitles[position];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just check in your manifest that which activity you declared as your launcher.

Comment: Simply launch the login activity first.

Comment: I don't have a login activity in my app. The login page is trigger by FirebaseAuth package. I am trying to create a login activity and set intent-filter to it. Thank you !!

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, the entire **[authentication process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** in which you'll see the exact behaviour that you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Thank you, I am watching your video, so there is no chance to use pre-built firebase UI to avoid this issue ?

Comment: As far I know, no. See the authentification process from that video. It works perfectly fine. If you have questions, please leave a comment. If  you think that my channel is hepful, give it a try and subscribe it.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Thank you, I will try it !

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, check which activity you have declared as a launcher antivity. It would be useful if you could show us your manifest file as well as your login activity code here.

Edit: Moreover, since you first `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`  and then

```
initializeScreen();
setupLogin();
```

it makes sense for your main activity to be displayed before your login process kicks in.

Comment: I don't have a login activity in my app. The login page is trigger by FirebaseAuth package. I am trying to create a login activity and set intent-filter to it. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest change the `<intent-filter>` to your LoginActivity

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

change the above lines

Comment: I don't have a login activity in my app. The login page is trigger by FirebaseAuth package. I am trying to create a login activity and set intent-filter to it. Thank you !!